# Scilab, get the last index of the maximum element in a vector

Tags: scilab

Given a vector, `A=[1,2,10,10,10,1]`, `[m,k]=max(A)` returns k=3.
How to get the last index of the maximum element? In this example, I want to get 5.

The most succinct way I can think of is: `[m,k]=max(A($:-1:1))`

Is there a better way or does scilab provide a parameter to do this? Reversing a large vertex is not a good idea in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use the find command

You can use the [find](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.3/en_US/find.html) command to get all indices of the maximum:

```
indices = find(A==max(A))
last = max(indices)
```

### Implement it yourself

Or if you want a single pass, you can implement it yourself:

```
//Create a c-function with your wanted behaviour
f1=['void max_array(int in_array[],int* in_num_elements,int *out_max, int *out_index)'
    '{' 
    'int i;'
    '*out_max=in_array[0];'
    '*out_index=-1;'
    'for (i=0; i<*in_num_elements; i++)'
    '{' 
        'if(in_array[i]>=*out_max)'
        '{'
             '*out_max=in_array[i];'
             '*out_index=i;'
        '}'
      '}'
 '}'];

//Place it in a file in the current directory
mputl(f1,'max_array.c')

//Create the shared library (a gateway, a Makefile and a loader are
//generated.
ilib_for_link('max_array','max_array.c',[],"c")

//Load the library
exec loader.sce

//Create wrapper for readability
function [m,k] = last_max(vector)
    [m, k] = call('max_array', vector, 1,'i', length(vector),2,'i', 'out',[1,1],3,'i',[1,1],4,'i');
    // Because c is zero-indexed add 1
    k = k + 1
endfunction

//Your data
A=[1,2,10,10,10,1];

//Call function on your data
[m,k] = last_max(A)
disp("Max value is " + string(m) + " at index " + string(k) )
```

Comment: Thanks. Still, it visits the vector twice. Is there a way not testing all the elements twice?

Comment: Thanks a lot. If for loop is the only way.... Quoted from 'INTRODUCTION TO SCILAB', "Vectorization enables to perform fast computations,
even in an interpreted environment like Scilab. This is why the for loop should be used only when there is no other way to perform the same computation with vectorized functions."

Comment: This is direct c code, it is not possible to do it any faster. Calling max(), min() is implemented as a for loop in c-code as well. See the sources of the functions [here](http://gitweb.scilab.org/?p=scilab.git;a=tree;f=scilab/routines/int;h=22cd210181fcc2f3f9c07d553aa4e9595ad85ee0;hb=b21698ae4b04105c688051a9afc7074dfcff3353).
The introduction refers to the for-loop in scilab. This is because scilab is an interpreted language. The c-code is compiled code. If you would like to measure which is quicker you could use [profiling](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.4.1/en_US/profile.html)